# Use UIView tag as the key to an NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, uiview, nsdictionary

I want to use a UIView tag as the key for an NSMutableDictionary.  However, the compiler objects to me using an NSInteger as a key.  I want to do the following:

```
NSInteger elementKey = _viewBeingDragged.tag;
myClass* element = [_model.elements objectForKey:elementKey];
```

How can I use elementKey as my dictionary key?

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992315/uiview-as-dictionary-key

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Rather create an NSString for the key, although you could use any NSCopying conform object:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",elementKey];
```

Comment: Your code snippet is incorrect, since you aren't passing an argument to match the "%d" format specifier. Also, using a string as a key when `NSNumber` would be a more natural fit is a bad idea and potentially unsafe. For example, for 64-bit, "%d" is not the right specifier for `NSInteger`, so you could get the same string for two different tags.

Answer (score 2):

A `NSInteger` is not an object, and cannot be used as a key. You can wrap it in a [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead:

```
NSNumber* elementKey = [NSNumber numberWithInt:_viewBeingDragged.tag];
myClass* element = [_model.elements objectForKey:elementKey];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumber* elementKey = [NSNumber numberWithInt:_viewBeingDragged.tag];
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with both @Mario and @EvanMulawski but I prefer using strings for my key. Oh, and as for the reason that the compiler rejects the use of an `NSInteger` is that `NSInteger`s are pretty much equivalent to `long int`s.

```
NSString* elementKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",_viewBeingDragged.tag];
//or NSNumber* elementKey = [NSNumber numberWithInt:_viewBeingDragged.tag];
myClass* element = [_model.elements objectForKey:elementKey];
```

Comment: Yeah, as I wrote, I also prefer strings, since it's safe then to use kvc.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in an `NSNumber` literal.

```
myClass* element = _model.elements[@(_viewBeingDragged.tag)];
```

And assignment:

```
NSInteger tag = view.tag;
myClass *value;
_model.elements[@(tag)] = value;
```